# *One* answer gets incomplete "flag" menu — cannot flag as VLQ

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging

I was going to flag [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/337687/150988) as “not an answer”
(it’s little more than a bunch of links) when I noticed

[image]

that the “flagging” dialog box didn’t include the “very low quality” option:

[image]

which is available on other answers.

What’s special about this answer, that it cannot be flagged as VLQ?

Comment: Looks like the VLQ flag option disappears if the answer has a positive score.

Comment: Wow!  So simple!  I don't recall noticing that before.

Comment: Yes. I guess if at least one person thinks the answer is useful **it just can't** be VLQ, right? :/

Comment: I wonder whether I should delete this now.  In hindsight, it feels like a dumb question, but it could be useful to others anyway.

Comment: @DavidPostill - What a silly system.  I have seen people give an upvote to obvious spam.  If it is link only then use that option.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but then you can still flag as spam.

Comment: I occasionally get a flag menu with only one or two options, including the custom reason.  I assumed it was because the post is already being reviewed in the system, and only "new" reasons need to be entered for consideration.

Comment: I just tried to flag one of **my own answers** (0 votes) ;) The only option was "In need of moderator intervention". So at least I know it can't be Spam, NAA, VLQ or Rude/Abusive :/

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yeah, we're all perfect in our own eyes.  :-)  ⁠

Comment: Scott, no, it's because the system knows that someone with @DavidPostill's record couldn't possibly have a post that isn't exemplary, so it doesn't waste electrons.

Comment: @fixer1234 lol ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments and on this [Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258895/why-is-the-option-very-low-quality-sometimes-hidden-in-flag-menu), VLQ is no longer shown for post having a positive score.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The MSE question implicitly raises without resolving the meta-question: is this a new rule? (Starkeen has over a year tenure on the site, and he seemed to be as surprised as I was to stumble upon the abridged menu.) Oded(♦) asks the counter-question, “Why flag before voting? Voting is the first and most important thing to do.” I would respond, “Why vote before flagging? I don’t want the answer to sink to the bottom of the score-sorted list; I want to push it into a review queue, where my peers can vote to delete it.” Does having one more downvote get it deleted any faster?

Comment: In response to my meta-follow up-meta question, “is this a new rule?”, I just now stumbled on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93595/195817#93606 "Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous? — VLQ means the flagger thinks this post is beyond saving") from 2011, in which Jeff Atwood♦ says “… we now only allow VLQ on posts with a score of **zero or lower** for the **first seven days** …”